# Solr custom query parser "fl" parameter not returning desired result

Tags: json, parsing, plugins, solr

I am currently working on replacing an existing searching platform with Solr. I am new to Solr and currently using Solr Version 6.6.0. Legacy system accepts a JSON object with search parameters. Thus I was asked to implement a custom query parser which accepts a query string in JSON format.
Essentially NO other parameter is passed to Solr except "q" which contains all the required parameters encoded in a JSON formatted string. All the common parameters and local parameters required to execute the query is then extracted by the query parser itself.
    This feat was successfully achieved except the "fl" parameter will not give the expecting results. Which means query result composes of all the fields that are present in the document. Code looks like this;

```
public static final String FIELD_LIST = "fl";
```

Collection for storing the key value pairs.

```
HashMap<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Decoding and formatting the field list.

```
String ifld = getFieldList();
```

Parameters are put in the collection thus.

```
paramMap.put(Constants.FIELD_LIST,ifld);
```

SolrParams are then generated.

```
return SolrParams.toSolrParams(new NamedList<>(paramMap));
```

Each and every query parameter is processed this way and finally in the query parsers parse() method i have this.

```
//calls the factory method to get the appropriate request type translator
        JSONRequestTranslator jrt = (JSONRequestTranslator)JSONQParser.getTranslator(requestType);

//converts the arguments to solrparams.
        qstr = jrt.getQueryString();
        localParams = jrt.getLocalParams();
        params = jrt.getParams();
        req.setParams(SolrParams.wrapDefaults(params, this.req.getParams()));

        return jrt.parse(qstr, localParams, params, req);
```

parse() method in classes implementing the JSONRequestTranslator interface looks like this

```
@Override
public Query parse(String qstr, SolrParams localParams, SolrParams params, SolrQueryRequest req) throws SyntaxError {
    return new DisMaxQParser(qstr, localParams, params, req).parse();       
}
```

This works fine but the "fl" parameter seems to have no effect. I don't have a default setting in solrconfig.xml file and while i'm debugging i always find the "fl" parameter set to correct value. I have tried several other approaches like writing custom search component plugins but  please explain how to fix this and what am i missing here. Thank you.

Comment: could you take a look into debugQuery and get understanding what has been populated in the fl field?

Comment: fl field in params under the responseHeader is not populated. In fact, none of the parameters are present there. i think this is because i do not define any parameter in the request it self. but when i was debugging remotely the fl field was populated just fine.

Comment: im not sure, i got you right. So, fl param isn't set in JSONRequestTranslator? Could you provide, what you have wrote there?

Comment: no, actually. JSONRequestTranslator interface is a facade for providing a QParser.

Comment: could you please reformulate your question and add some additional piece of code? with remarks where you see content of fol during debugging and where you don't

Comment: I have edited the question to insert a small piece of code to show what happens inside the JSONRequestTranslator implemented classes. Anyway i was able to solve the problem using another approach. Which involves in designing a custom search component and processing the request before it was processed by the query parser. That way it was possible to directly inject the fl parameters in to the response. But i would be really grateful if you could provide an answer to the question and give me an idea about what happens exactly.

Comment: Can you confirm that every field you are requesting in fl has the attribute stored=true set in the schema?